# discord.py add a role to all members of a role

Tags: python, discord

I want to add a role to all members who have another role in discord.py, is it possible? I already tried doing role.members.add_roles(role), but that didnt work, and im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if your_role in member.roles:
        await member.add_roles(the_other_role)
```